# " Expected token ',' " when using transition property inside a signal handler in QML

Tags: qml, syntax-error

I want to make a transition for a `Rectangle` in the event of a mouse hover.I followed [this tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlexampletoggleswitch.html#transition) and created a `MouseArea` like this :

```
MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: {
            rMT.color = 'red'                    // rMT is my rectangle's id (rectangle_mouse_tracking)
            transitions: Transition {            // Expected token ','
                NumberAnimation {
                    property : "width"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                    duration : 200
                }
            }
        }
    ...
    ...
```

*There are other possible ways to make an animation , but I want to know what's wrong with the above code?

Currently I'm a noob in QML.So sorry if the question is a little silly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations defined in transitions are executed when the property changes.

If you want the animation to be executed when the `width` changes, change the width in onEntered and transition defined in Rectangle will be executed.

Syntax error is because `transitions` must be in Rectange{} not in onEntered {}

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick 2.0
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        id: rMT
        width: 400
        height:400
        x:0
        color: 'blue'
        border.color: 'black'
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                rMT.color = 'red'
                rMT.width = 100
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition{
            NumberAnimation {
                property : "width"
                from: 400
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                duration : 2000
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok.But "duration" and "easing" have no effect at all.Why?

Comment: Transitions are using with States if you are not using states use behaviours.